# How to Remove Item In the Django Admin for ManyToMany Multiple Select

Tags: django, django-admin

My Django admin interface is rendering a multiple select, reflecting a many-to-many relationship between, say a Contact and an Email. E.g. I can choose multiple emails per contact in the add Contact page. The emails are stored in a separate table that contains just the emails. In this case a Contact can have more than one email, and an email can relate to more than on Contact (emails can be shared between multiple contacts).

From the admin interface is it possible to remove one or all of the emails from a Contact that is already created? A multi-select is rendered, but I don't see a way to remove an email from an existing Contact. Is it some setting/argument used in the email admin class?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, it depends on your models, it depends on what did you use `ManyToMany` Field or `OneToOne` Field. If you use `ManyToMany` Field then it means it relates from multiple  contacts and if you want to delete then try to delete one email from the contacts.

Comment: It's a `ManyToMany`, are you saying I should be able to remove them from `Contact` on the `Email` side?

Comment: I stated it was a ManyToMany, and the point of my question is I can't remove existing emails from a Contact.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not letting me un downvote your answer, even though it's correct. I'll try later.

Comment: I believe if you edit your answer SO will allow me to upvote your answer and take away the downvote.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking the email would come off the multi select, but of course it just gets selected/unselected. Standard multiselects are notoriously confusing for users, and even I got confused...